# Hibernate: Set a default in many-to-one class mapping

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, mapping, hql

I am trying to map a class Language to a class User.

Many to one mapping is working fine, and through the functionality of the app I can set the value from it's default of null to a particular value.

The problem is that I'd like to set the default mapping to idLanguage 1, but when it maps everything is set to null.

I have tried:

```
< many-to-one name="language" class="com. \etc\ .language.Language" column="language" default="1" lazy="false" />
```

However that gives me an error "Attribute default must be declared for element type Many To One.

What to do?

(note: language is mapped to language object in user class, rather than a language id. Setting in the app puts the id of the language in the language column, replacing null value)

Answer (score 1):

I hope the languages will be seed data in your application. Then have a separate **langId** field in the User mapping and set it to 1. The Object mapping can be used while loading the User bean.So modify the mapping as below.

```
< many-to-one name="language" class="com. \etc\ .language.Language" column="language" lazy="false" insert="false" update="false"/>

<property name="langId" column="language"/>
```

This way it will be more performative as you don't have to fetch the Languages bean from the DB before you save the User bean. Also on load of User the languages will be available to.

Comment: Ok, I tried that and got this error: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Null value was assigned to a property of primitive type setter of com.\etc\.user.User.langID

Comment: That is with private int langID = 1; w/ get/set in User class

Comment: Use the setLangID() method in the User class to set the value of langId to 1 before you save the user bean.

Comment: Not working I'm afraid, It's giving me in-thread null-pointers.

Comment: It didn't work, so I'm trying to set a simple if(user.getLanguage==null){Language newLang = new Language(); newLang.setIdLang(1); user.setLanguage(newLang)}; This still gives a null-pointer. Surely this should see the null and go ok, do this. :(

Comment: share your full mapping of User in the Qs.

Comment: Can't I'm afraid, it's part of a proprietary piece of software. Sorry.

Comment: Should explain, I've changed the class names, it's sensitive material.

Comment: Ok. Don't create a new language and set it to user. It won't work. Instead of that use the **langId** available in the user and set that directly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4530/discussion-between-manupk-and-spuriosity)